# Check ListBox before Adding New Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I am trying to check that an item doesn't already exist in a list box before I add the new item.

```
            if (TeamNameTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (TeamNameListBox.Items.FindByValue(TeamNameListBox.Text) == null)
            {
                TeamNameListBox.Items.Add(TeamNameTextBox.Text);
                TeamNameTextBox.Text = "";

                int teamCountUpdate = TeamNameListBox.Items.Count;
                if (teamCountUpdate == 1)
                {
                    TeamCount.Text = teamCountUpdate.ToString() + " Team";
                }
                else
                {
                    TeamCount.Text = teamCountUpdate.ToString() + " Teams";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AddTeamSeasonError.Text = "This team has already been added";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AddTeamSeasonError.Text = "Please select a team";
        }
```

I have got it to check if the text box is blank, but I need to check that the item a user is trying to add is not already in the the list box.

I have tried the line:

```
if (TeamNameListBox.Items.FindByValue(TeamNameListBox.Text) == null)
```

But that doesn't work, any suggestions on how I can do the check?

Comment: -1 without comment is rude so I +1'ed to cancel it out..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check List Box before Adding New Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532657/check-list-box-before-adding-new-item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TeamNameTextBox.Text))
{
    if (!TeamNameListBox.Items.Contains(TeamNameTextBox.Text))
    {
        TeamNameListBox.Items.Add(TeamNameTextBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        // item already exists in listbox
    }
}
else
{
    // textbox is empty
}
```