# Check List Box before Adding New Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I am trying to check that an item doesn't already exist in a list box before I add the new item.

```
            if (TeamNameTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (TeamNameListBox.Items.FindByValue(TeamNameListBox.Text) == null)
            {
                TeamNameListBox.Items.Add(TeamNameTextBox.Text);
                TeamNameTextBox.Text = "";

                int teamCountUpdate = TeamNameListBox.Items.Count;
                if (teamCountUpdate == 1)
                {
                    TeamCount.Text = teamCountUpdate.ToString() + " Team";
                }
                else
                {
                    TeamCount.Text = teamCountUpdate.ToString() + " Teams";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AddTeamSeasonError.Text = "This team has already been added";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AddTeamSeasonError.Text = "Please select a team";
        }
```

I have got it to check if the text box is blank, but I need to check that the item a user is trying to add is not already in the the list box.

I have tried the line:

```
if (TeamNameListBox.Items.FindByValue(TeamNameListBox.Text) == null)
```

But that doesn't work, any suggestions on how I can do the check?

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. I am voting to close the other question, you have asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think you should at least try to use `TeamNameTextBox` instead of `TeamNameListBox` as argument

```
if (TeamNameListBox.Items.FindByValue(TeamNameTextBox.Text) == null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if (!TeamNameListBox.Items.Contains(TeamNameTextBox.Text))
                TeamNameListBox.Items.Add(TeamNameTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean

```
// search if the textbox value is found in the list. this comment shouldn't be part of the code
if (TeamNameListBox.Items.FindByValue(TeamNameTextBox.Text) == null)
```

instead of

```
if (TeamNameListBox.Items.FindByValue(TeamNameListBox.Text) == null) // code from question
```

EDIT: There is no need to put the name of the type of the control next to the variable.
i.e. instead of `TeamNameListBox`, use `teamNames`. And, instead of `TeamNameTextBox`, use `teamName`.